# Mingw for c installation issue

Tags: c, windows, mingw

## When I try to install mingw for c for my widows11 64 bit system it says "the file has been downloaded incorrectly". Can anyone help?

I tried the online installer of mingw for c on 64 bit in windows 11. I expected the smooth installation of this software but when I try to install it's says "The file has been downloaded incorrectly"

Comment: A first guess is that the file **has** been downloaded incorrectly. You didn't tell us how, or from where, you got the file.

Answer (score 1):

MinGW is quite outdated. You should use the newer MinGW-w64. You can get a standalone build from https://winlibs.com/ or if you plan on using [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) you can install via its package manager `pacman`.